# slick slider with animations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, css-animations, slick.js

I am using *slick slider* with animation on my site. everything works great except when I drag slide if not moved to the next or previous slide I don't want to use animation.

```
<div id="my_slider">
  <div id="item">
    <div id="name" class="hidden">slide1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <div id="name" class="hidden">slide2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item">
    <div id="name" class="hidden">slide3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxc464yd/1/)

Comment: Are you talking about the zoom animation on the slide text e.g. "slide2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an `id` of `name` for multiple items, which is not valid. `id`s must always be unique. Instead of targeting the slide names using an `id`, you can assign a common class e.g. `slide-name`

In order for the functionality to work as you wish, you will have to make use of an additional event called `setPosition`, which runs after the `afterChange` event. However, before you introduce additional event handlers, you'll need to keep track of the current slide using the `beforeChange` event and then check if the next slide matches the current slide in the `afterChange` event. If the current slide and next slide match (no change has taken place), skip the animation. If they don't match (a change has taken place), trigger the animation.

Use the `afterChange` event to initiate the animation only if the current slide and the next slide do not match i.e. the active slide has changed. Use variables to keep track of the current and next slide e.g. `currSlide` and `nextSlide` respectively. Then in the `setPosition` event, you can trigger the animation by comparing `currSlide` to `nextSlide`.

Finally, I've added a helper method to apply a `class` of `hidden` to the slide names that are not currently visible. This prevents the text from appearing prematurely and ruining the animation. I'm calling this method on `init` as well as in the `setPosition` event.

**Updated Html**

```
<div id="my_slider">
  <div class="item">
    <div id="name1" class="slide-name hidden">slide1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div id="name2" class="slide-name hidden">slide2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div id="name3" class="slide-name hidden">slide3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#my_slider').on('init', function(event, slick) {
  $('.slick-active .slide-name').removeClass('hidden');
  applyHiddenClass();
})

$('#my_slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  speed: 900,
});

var currSlide = 0;
var nextSlide = 0;

function applyHiddenClass() {
  $.each($('.slick-slide'), function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-hidden') == 'true') {
      $(this).find('.slide-name').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.slide-name').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
}

$('#my_slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  nextSlide = currentSlide;
  if (nextSlide !== currSlide) {
    $('.slick-active .slide-name').removeClass('animated zoomIn');
    $('.slick-active .slide-name').addClass('hidden');
  }
});

$('#my_slider').on('setPosition', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  if (nextSlide !== currSlide) {
    $('.slick-active .slide-name').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.slick-active .slide-name').addClass('animated zoomIn');
  }
  applyHiddenClass();
});

$('#my_slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  currSlide = currentSlide;
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xxc464yd/5/)**

If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: "ids must always be unique", yet you put some replicated ids on the wrapper divs. Good solution tho.

Answer (score 0):

try this; set speed to zero to disable animation:

```
$('#my_slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  speed: 0,
});
```

Comment: I don't wanna disable animation. I only want to use it if slider moved to the next or previous slide.